# Looking for a way that a page load time can decrease for a page that has lots of HTML5 audio

Tags: html, audio, preloading

In the instance of a page with a great deal of HTML5 audio, and to maximize the load time efficiency (i.e. - to make it load as fast as possible), couldn't we set a value in the preload parameter to achieve this? Currently, I have preload set to "auto", but I what if we want to not have any page loading ALL of the audio before the page is completely "loaded"? Since in the instance of a user requiring ALL of the audio at any one visit, or even simultaneously is unlikely, how would we achieve that the audio files are only loaded on-demand, and thus achieving maximum load efficiency for the scenario?

Thanks in advance for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `preload` attribute to `none`:

> `auto`
>   The author thinks that the browser should load the entire audio file when the page loads
>   `metadata`
>   The author thinks that the browser should load only metadata when the page loads
>   `none`
>   The author thinks that the browser should NOT load the audio file when the page loads

Taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_preload.asp)